# How can I invite someone on Chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

This question has nothing to do with music but I didn't know where to ask sorry.

I want to create a chat room and invite someone to it, how do I do that?

And if the person isn't online does he still get the message?

Does it go to his inbox or something?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110330/192187 for more detail

Answer (score 2):

As per the [chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications), you can ping users that have been in chat before with an `@` sign.

There is a "super-ping" function that [can summon any user from any site](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2370), but it is only available to moderators.

Comment: You can only ping users who have been in the room before. So if I want to create a new room and invite a user I cant do that, right?

Comment: Ok, so I just created a room and I want to invite JJmusicnotes who has never been in the room. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You would be much better served by just using the main chat room. All rooms are public anyway.